# How can I make a sprite react with another sprite in HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, collision-detection

I am new to this and I am trying to make it so that my sprite reacts when coming into contact with another sprite or a border.

I see collision detection working for images that are drawn with code but what if I am using .png?

I cannot figure out how to stop my character when they hit an edge or how to stop them or make them react when hitting another sprite within my canvas.

This is what I have though if anyone could help me.

```
<head>

function leftArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human-left-step.png';}

function rightArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
element.src = "images/model-human-right-step.png";}

function upArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human-back-step.png';}

function downArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human-step.png';}


function moveSelectionPressed(event) {                    
switch (event.keyCode) {
case 37:leftArrowPressed();break;
case 39:rightArrowPressed();break;
case 38:upArrowPressed();break;
case 40:downArrowPressed();break;
}
};


function leftArrowUnPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human-left.png';}

function rightArrowUnPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
element.src = "images/model-human-right.png";}

function upArrowUnPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human-back.png';}

function downArrowUnPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("avatar");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
element.src = 'images/model-human.png';}


function moveSelectionUnPressed(event) {                    
switch (event.keyCode) {
case 37:leftArrowUnPressed();break;
case 39:rightArrowUnPressed();break;
case 38:upArrowUnPressed();break;
case 40:downArrowUnPressed();break;
}
};


function gameLoop()
{// change position based on speed
moveSelection(); setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);}

</head>


<body onload="gameLoop();" onkeydown="moveSelectionPressed(event)" onkeyup="moveSelectionUnPressed(event)"'>

<img id='sprite1' src='images/model-human.png' style='position: absolute; left: 1; right: 1; top: 100; bottom: auto;' width='70' height='70'>

<img id='object' src='images/weapon-sword.png' style='position: absolute; left: 80%; right: 1; top: 200; bottom: auto;' width='36' height='22'>

</body>
```